# Good-looking but simple-to-setup embedded analytics

Tags: data-visualization, reporting, business-intelligence

Most of BI and reporting tools are complex and powerful.
I need a very basic reporting design tools, ability to embed reports and dashboards in external web app as white label, minimal computational power, BUT very very good looking final results. I need to connect with db sources, mysql or AWS/aurora/mysql ( google analytics or logging data will be a plus).

Most of tools I find are very powerful BI-wise but don't give much power on final look and feel. 
I would like something like D3.js visualization power, backed by a simpler report design tools, without building it myself

Comment: By "embedded", do you mean it should run on a web page? Should all of the processing be made in the web page itself, or on a separate server? I don't think a web page can open a connection to MySQL.

Comment: Nope, it can't. As confirmed by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020751/can-javascript-connect-with-mysql)

Comment: By embedded I mean that an external BI tool, can generate an embed link to visualize the data. Could be through iframe or through a js library that takes care of visualization only (not calculation 6 db connection)